# How to use java8 to collect this map

Tags: java, java-stream, collect

```
class Person {
    private String sex;
    private List<String> nameList;

    public Person(String sex, String name) {
        this.sex = sex;
        this.nameList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.nameList.add(name);
    }


    public Person(String sex, List<String> nameList) {
        this.sex = sex;
        this.nameList = nameList;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p1 = new Person("M", "name1");
    Person p2 = new Person("M", "name2");
    Person p3 = new Person("F", "name3");
    Person p4 = new Person("F", "name4");
    Person p5 = new Person("F", "name5");

    List<Person> ps = Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);

    // sex --> Person
    Map<String, Person> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    ps.forEach(p -> {
        Person pp = map1.get(p.getSex());
        if (pp == null) {
            pp = new Person(p.getSex(), p.getNameList());
            map1.put(p.getSex(), pp);
        } else {
            pp.getNameList().addAll(p.getNameList());
        }
    });
    System.out.println(map1);

    Map<String, Person> map2 = ps.stream().collect(/* how to write here*/);
    System.err.println(map2);
}
```

I want to user `ps.stream().collect()` to solve this problem like main`()`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a map of Person's Name (key) to Person (value)

```
Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getName(), p -> p);
```

Comment: i want to set map2 as the same as map1

Answer (score 0):

i know the answer;

```
Map<String, Person> map2 = ps.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getSex, p -> p, (oldValue, newValue) -> {
                oldValue.getNameList().addAll(newValue.getNameList());
                return oldValue;
            }));
```